# How to display the correct and incorrect answers at the end in below Java code?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a quiz type java program and I need to put the correct and incorrect things at the end after finishing all the questions but i have no idea how to do it. I have tried all in my knowledge which is really not that good and again I have no idea how to do it
Here is my example code:

```
import java.util.*;
static Scanner console =  new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] x = new int [4][1];
        char answer = 0;

        System.out.print("1+1 \n A. 2 \n B. \n C \n D.");
            for (int q = 0 ; q< 1 ; q++) {
            for (int w = 0 ; w< 1  ; w++) {
                x[0][0] = 'A';
                x[1][0] = 'B';
                x[2][0] = 'C';
                x[3][0] = 'D';
                answer   = console.next().charAt(0);
                if (answer == x[0][0]) {
                    System.out.print(" Q1 Correct");
                }else 
                    System.out.print(" Q1 Incorrect");
        }
        }   

        System.out.print("\n 2+2 \n A. 2 \n B.4\n C \n D.");
        for (int q1 = 0 ; q1< 1  ; q1++) {
            for (int w1 = 0 ; w1< 1  ; w1++) {
                x[0][0] = 'A';
                x[1][0] = 'B';
                x[2][0] = 'C';
                x[3][0] = 'D';
                answer  = console.next().charAt(0);

                if ( answer == x[1][0]) {
                    System.out.print(" Q2 Correct");
                }else 
                    System.out.print("Q2  Incorrect");

        }
        }

        System.out.print("\n3-1 \n A. 2 \n B. \n C \n D.");
        for (int q1 = 0 ; q1< 1  ; q1++) {
            for (int w1 = 0 ; w1< 1  ; w1++) {
                x[0][0] = 'A';
                x[1][0] = 'B';
                x[2][0] = 'C';
                x[3][0] = 'D';
                answer  = console.next().charAt(0);

                if (answer == x[0][0]) {
                    System.out.print(" Q3 Correct");
                }else
                    System.out.print(" Q3 Incorrect");
                }
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you think about a way to store the questions and answers in a textfile, for example, instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: you can write all the answers in List, for example and then after all questions passed, check lists elements one by one for correctness

Comment: Instead of printing the results after every question, put them in some array or list and print at the end.

Comment: Your for-loops are maybe not very useful, because they all just get executed only once. What was your intention behind those for-loops?

Comment: Im not so sure , can u suggest an alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a better model it will be easier to work with the logic. Example:

**Answer POJO**

```
package com.company;

class Answer {

    private final String letter;
    private final String value;

    Answer(String letter, String value) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.value = value;
    }

    String getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Question POJO**

```
import java.util.List;

class Question {

    private final String question;
    private final List<Answer> answers;
    private final String correctAnswer;

    Question(String question, List<Answer> answers, String correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

**Main loop**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;

public class Main {

    private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static List<String> POSSIBLE_ANSWERS = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D");

    private static List<Answer> createAnswers(List<String> values) {
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < values.size() && i < POSSIBLE_ANSWERS.size(), i -> i + 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Answer(POSSIBLE_ANSWERS.get(i), values.get(i)))
                .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var questions = List.of(
                new Question("1+1", createAnswers(List.of("2", "3", "4", "5")), "A"),
                new Question("2+2", createAnswers(List.of("2", "3", "4", "5")), "C"));

        var results = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
            var question = questions.get(i);
            System.out.printf("Question %d: %s%n", i + 1, question.getQuestion());
            for (var answer : question.getAnswers()) {
                System.out.printf("- %s. %s%n", answer.getLetter(), answer.getValue());
            }

            String user_input;
            do {
                System.out.printf("Chose one of %s:%n", POSSIBLE_ANSWERS);
                user_input = String.valueOf(console.next().charAt(0));

            } while (!POSSIBLE_ANSWERS.contains(user_input));

            var result = question.getCorrectAnswer().equals(user_input);
            results.add(result);
            System.out.println(result + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Results: " + results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want is to visualize at the end of execution the test's results.
At the beginning of your code, just below the variable char answer you could create two more int vars called for example positiveAnswer and negativeAnswer. It looks like this.

```
int[][] x = new int[4][1];
char answer = 0;
int positiveAnswer = 0;
int negativeAnswer = 0;
```

Then, in each of the for blocks you will have to add the result on corresponding variable, depending on the result. You will have to do this as i said on EVERY TIME that you ask the question.

```
for (int q = 0; q < 1; q++) {

    for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
        x[0][0] = 'A';
        x[1][0] = 'B';
        x[2][0] = 'C';
        x[3][0] = 'D';
        answer = console.next().charAt(0);
        if (answer == x[0][0]) {
            System.out.print(" Q1 Correct");
            positiveAnswer++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(" Q1 Incorrect");
            negativeAnswer++;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the positiveAnswer++ or negativeAnswer++ has to be incremented.

At the end you could print the result with format like this

```
System.out.printf("Positive answer %d Negative answer %d", positiveAnswer, negativeAnswer);
```

This is not the most orthodox way to implement, but it could help you to improve your development skills doing it manually!